# Check if a ParseFile is empty

Tags: android, parse-platform

My ParseUser class has a custom column called "profile_photo" which is a ParseFile of a photo. I have attached a photo file to a ParseUser instance and I can see on my app users dashboard that the profile_photo column for that user is filled with that file and the other users have "undefined" set for that column, as expected. Now on my code I need to check if a user has a profile photo attached or not. How do I do this. I have tried to check that using the isDataAvailable() but it always returns true even if the value for profile_photo is "undefined" on the dashboard. I have also tried the following:

```
ParseFile photo = user.get("profile_photo");
photo.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() { 
   @Override public void done(byte[] data, ParseException pfe) { 
      if(pfe == null) { 
         // byte array data always returns something! data.length > 0, always, even for undefined... 
       }
   }
});
```

But as you can see by the comments, the data array is never empty even if the ParseFile attached to the ParseUser in question is "undefined".

I would much appreciate if you could tell me or indicate me a way to clearly identify if a parsefile is empty or not.

Best Regards

Comment: What is your way to obtain the file? `ParseFile file = object.getParseFile("column_name")` returns `null` if the file is undefined.

Comment: I'm obtaining the file by doing ParseFile photo  = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get("profile_photo"); and I just discovered that maybe this returns the id of the file instead of the image data: https://www.parse.com/questions/parsefile-pf-parsefile-objectgetlogo-returns-string-instead-of-file. I still have to confirm this on my code

Comment: I confirmed what I exposed on my previous comment above the get("profile_photo") does indeed return the ID of the file instead the actual data (bytes) of the photo. @Lamorak you may want to answer my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong method to obtain your file. If you use `get("column_name")` on a column which is `ParseFile`, this method will return the file id. You should instead use

```
ParseFile file = object.getParseFile("column_name");
```

which will return **null** if the file is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Might help others, can use ContainsKey on the query function to see if a ParseUser/ ParseObject has a file under the attribute defined -

```
    if (ParseObject.ContainsKey("file_column_name"))
      // get the file and do whatever you want with it here
    else
      // error
```

An even more efficient version of the same code would be -

```
    if (ParseObject.TryGetValue("file_column_name", out ParseFile file))
      // do whatever you want with the file here
```